# How to remove a configuration in Eclipse GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have migrated my application development to a new PC and now when I run the application (Run > Run as > Web application). I get the "HTML Page Selection" popup in which I select my application. However, now I also get a "Choose a launch configuration:" popup which lists "AwardTracker" and "AwardTrackwer.html". They both do the same thing. How do I remove one of these please (this is more annoying than anything else)?

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to remove a configuration in Eclipse GWT

Simply select any **Web Application** and click on **RED X** icon displayed on top right of it to remove an existing configuration.

Once a Web Application is configured then there is no need to create it again. Just launch it from existing one to avoid it choosing a launch configuration again.

Once configured then **don't** run it again by RIGHT click on the project to run as Web Application. Simply select from the existing one form the tool bar as shown in below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again Braj.  Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

Click Run > Run Configurations > your configuration (typically, a name of your HTML or JSP file) > Arguments.

Make sure you only have the path that you want to launch.